# Парадигматические и синтагматические отношения

Tags: лексика, семантика, терминология

Пожалуйста, объясните мне, что такое парадигматические отношения, а также синтагматические отношения. Очень помогут примеры.

Comment: Написать реферат, эссе?

Answer (score 3):

Парадигма (греч. – пример, образец) – **система форм одного и того же слова** как образец склонения или спряжения, а также система звуков речи, значений слов, система форм конструкций, объединённых в один тип.

Парадигматические отношения – это те отношения, которые объединяют единицы языка в группы, разряды, категории. **На парадигматические отношения опираются, например, система согласных, система склонения, синонимический ряд.** При использовании языка парадигматические отношения позволяют выбрать нужную единицу, а также образовывать слова, их формы по аналогии с имеющимися в языке.

**Существуют парадигма падежа существительного 1-го склонения, парадигма спряжения глаголов настоящего времени и т.д.**

Парадигмой называют отношения между единицами, которые могут занять место друг друга в одной позиции.

Например, *Роста он был высокого (среднего, низкого).*

*Слов-о, слов-а, слов-у* и т.д.

В этих примерах слова высокий, низкий, средний и флексии -о, -а, -у сводят в один парадигматический ряд.

Синтагма (греч.– нечто соединённое) – **то же, что словосочетание, а также интонационно-смысловая единица и образец синтаксической единицы.**

Это интонационно-смысловое единство, которое выражает в данном контексте и в данной ситуации одно понятие и может состоять из одного слова, группы слов и целого предложения.

Синтагматика включает в себя языковые правила сочетаемости одноуровневых единиц языка и их реализаций в речи. **Элементарное синтагматическое отношение двучленно: например, согласный + гласный в слоге, словообразовательная основа + словообразовательный аффикс, подлежащее + сказуемое и др**.

Синтагматические отношения объединяют единицы языка в их одновременной последовательности. **На синтагматических отношениях строятся слова как совокупность морфем и слогов, словосочетания и аналитические наименования, предложения (как совокупности членов предложения) и сложные предложения**. При использовании языка синтагматические отношения позволяют одновременно использовать две и более единиц языка.